# don't know why im receiving Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a WQS analysis in r using the code from the cran.r website but i keep getting the same message: Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

i expected there to be results of mixtures affecting a certain outcome

```
surfacearea <- mixturewcovariates$A.Surface.Area
lnpfas<- mixturewcovariates[,c("Ln.PFHXS.", "Ln.PFOS.", "Ln.PFOA.", "Ln.PFNA.")]
subset_data <- mixturewcovariates[, c(6:9)]
results <- gwqs(A.Surface.Area ~ wqs, mix_name = subset_data, data = mixturewcovariates, 
                q = 4, validation = 0.6, b = 2, b1_pos = TRUE, 
                b1_constr = FALSE, family = "gaussian", seed = 2016)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, you haven't provided enough information that we can answer the question. Please have a look how to provide a [great MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. paste the output of `dput` of your data and include the packages you use. Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.